# Send Function keys through serial port Serial.Write()

Tags: c#, keyboard, serial-port

Can any one guide me how to send Function keys (F1 - F11) through serial port:

```
    string read_line;
    read_line = Console.ReadLine();
    SerPort.WriteLine(read_line);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no *standard* way of sending the function keys to the serial port. You need to define your own id's for the keys (string or byte), fill it accordingly to user's current choice and send it. On the other side of the serial port whatever is listening/reading should know how to handle the input - this will be your own communication interface.

The function keys are *special* keys, so you need to use [Console.ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of *ReadLine*. A possible solution could look like this:

```
var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
string keyInfo = string.Empty;
byte keyInfoId = 0;
switch (key.Key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.F3: Console.WriteLine("F3 hit ..."); 
                        keyInfo = "F3"; 
                        keyInfoId = 0x3; 
                        break;
    case ConsoleKey.F5: Console.WriteLine("F5 hit ..."); 
                        keyInfo = "F5"; 
                        keyInfoId = 0x5; 
                        break;
    // ...
    default: Console.WriteLine("Not a function key"); break;
}
using (var serialPort = new SerialPort())
{
    serialPort.Open();
    serialPort.WriteLine(keyInfo);
    serialPort.Write(new byte[] { keyInfoId }, 0, 1);
    serialPort.Close();
}
```

You can send the the information to the serial port using [SerialPort.Write or SerialPort.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).