# sending 'F2' over serial port c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

i have some kind of parser that receive a configuration file, and it resolves its data. One possible type of data is Hex characters. I am formatting the Hex character ie(0D), and for most hex chars i am not facing problems. However, for the 'F2' key, I am not able to send it.
The following snippet is how i am resolving the Hex chars:

```
hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
{
     raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
}
return Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(raw);
```

I am sending data serially over a Gold x usb to serial. And all my data is passing including '\n\r'. For 'F2' i am using the Hex value of 'A1'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send Function keys through serial port Serial.Write()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143378/send-function-keys-through-serial-port-serial-write)

Comment: Already saw that post and tried it ... it did not work for me

Comment: That doesn't mean that you should post a duplicate question.  Like the other answer says, "There is no standard way of sending the function keys to the serial port."  Look at the specifications of the device you are trying to communicate with.  If the question is "How do I send 0xa1 over a serial port", that is entirely different - but the answer is just `SerialPort.WriteByte(0xa1)` (or the equivalent call using `.Write(byte[], int, int)`)

Comment: i did use SerialPort.WriteByte(0xa1) but i end up receiving a '?' at the receiver side

Comment: 0xa1 is non-printable in most character sets.  I don't know what you are expecting it to show up as.  See [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forming a char from the Byte array and then converting the char to string, and encoding this string using UTF-8 fixed the issue for me